# Notice: Undefined variable: dbRead in C:\vhosts\phpcs5\lesson07\workfiles\scripts\user_registration.php on line 28

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm getting this error and after checking for similar errors I verified the syntax is correct. The complete error is;

```
WRITE OK
READ OK
```

> Notice: Undefined variable: dbRead in C:\vhosts\phpcs5\lesson07\workfiles\scripts\user_registration.php on line 28
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function quoteInto() on a non-object in C:\vhosts\phpcs5\lesson07\workfiles\scripts\user_registration.php on line 28

My connection is defined as:

```
$dbwrite = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql($write);
$dbread =  new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql($read);
```

I did a test first to make sure it can see the database which is what the Write OK and Read OK are as follows;

```
if ($dbwrite->getConnection()) {
      echo 'WRITE OK<br/>';
  }
  if ($dbread->getConnection()) {
      echo 'READ OK';
  }
```

So I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

Comment: You need to provide us the lines from user_registration.php, at minimum 5 after and before line 28.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 1):

`dbRead` *is* undefined. You've defined `$dbread`. Note the capitalization.

Look through your code base (particularly user_registration.php line 28) and switch all instances to one or the other.